# Correct Cache Architecture for Multiple Sites

Tags: asp.net, caching, redis, appfabric

Im struggling with a scenario regarding accessing a single cache across multiple web applications on a single web server (IIS 8 / Windows Server 2012).

Currently we have a server with 16GB of memory, that runs just one site.
For arguments sake, lets say that this site consumes 10GB of memory on its own (alot I know)

It stores everything in `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`, where retrieval is super fast. A typical scenario would be retrieving 10,000 objects from this cache, which it can do in a couple of miliseconds.

It gets tricky when I want to add another web application to this server that is 99.9% identical to the other site running on the server, and ideally wants to access everything in this sites lighting fast HttpRuntime.Cache.

The problem im seeing is that this HttpRuntime.Cache cannot be shared across applications as far as im aware.

Ive tried AppFabric, Redis and NCache, all distributed cache agents, and the absolute quickest they can retrieve the same 10,000 objects is about 2 seconds which is no good for an on-demand website. (As an aside, Im pretty sure 1.999 of those 2 seconds are filled with deserialising which is also very cpu intensive)

Am I missing something obvious...a way for two web apps on one server to access a Cache that doesnt require costly serialisation/deserialisation? Or is it time to fork out for a new webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I cant be sure about this so I will try to make a guess :)

When using redis to get multiple keys, make sure you do it within a single transaction (MULTI/EXEC) or at least that you dont do 1 call per key as that is very slow and inefficient (the webserver would spend lots of time doing IO to redis).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your situation. In fact, many people face the same. I would encourage you

to use the Client Cache feature of NCache that lets you cache a subset of the entire

distributed cache in your .NET application's process memory.

With Client Cache, you can achieve your performance goals. And, you would still be able to build a very large cache due to the distributed cache behind the scenes. This is something you cannot do with a stand-alone Http Cache.

Let me know if you would like to talk to somebody in [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/Ncache) team one-on-one about this.